# Can a package be required only for tests, not for installation?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pandas, pip

I'm adding functionality to an existing pip-installable project, and the project owner feels that my adding of `pandas` to the setup.py installation requirements is 'too heavy', as the project should remain slim. The functionality I'm adding does not require `pandas` (because the functionality is operations on top of a `pandas.DataFrame` object), but the unit tests I wrote for it require invoking `pandas` to `setUp` a test DataFrame to mutate with.

Is there some way to require `pandas` only for the unit tests? Or do I just not add it to the requirements, and raise an error to manually install `pandas` when that unit test is run?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Option 1:

Use an "extra" with `setuptools`:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="your_app",
    ...
    install_requires=...
    extras_require={
        "dev": [
            "pytest", "pandas", "coverage",  # etc
        ]
    },
)
```

Now when you develop on the app, use:

```
pip install --editable '.[dev]'
```

#### Option 2:

Don't advertise the development requirements in the packaging metadata at all, just keep a development [requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/) in the project directory and mention in the README that developers should install those after checking out the source code

```
pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
```

Comment: I think `tests_require` is the better approach here since this creates an optional features which will never be available in production.

Comment: I previously used `tests_require`, but moved away from it because I do not like the way that installs the dependencies, you have less control in the CI.  Not everyone wants to use `python setup.py test` as the way to execute the test suite.

Comment: Still this approach requires knowledge about how to use optional features and advertises them when installing packages. There might be good reasons for this, but generally I would prefer to use the intended mechanisms before resorting to such a "hack". Also, maybe `tests_require` could be fixed in the future.

Comment: Many things in the Python packaging world are broken, and `tests_require` is arguably one of those things.  I don't find a `dev` extras tag to be a hack, on the contrary, I find it more flexible and powerful.

Comment: Sure, packaging is a nightmare, but you also lose some functionality with this approach. E.g. automatic dependency management for just using `python setup.py test`. Your solution is perfectly fine given your requirements, but I would refrain for promoting such "hacks" for people who might just be happy with the simple and semantically correct approach.

Comment: Not sure what counts as a "hack", but many well-respected open source projects prefer this approach, for example [`sentry`](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/35bb54b07d1bfc97a17fdbed1a3899c5b975f4a4/setup.py#L196-L201).

Comment: @languitar  This may change in the future, but [using extras is correct](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1197#issuecomment-290488597) and current (2017) according to dstufft (who probably knows more about Python packaging than anyone else in the world).

Answer (score 0):

For setuptools you can use `tests_require` in a similar fashion to `install_requires` to list packages that are only required for testing.

Cf. https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/keywords.html?highlight=tests_require

Comment: Since many people are using `pip`/`virtuelenv` combo for development currently (and the question explicitly said "pip-installable project"), I think the answer should at least mention it: `pandas` would get downloaded to the project's setup directory, not installed in the virtualenv.  This is likely not what the developer wanted nor expected.

Comment: Deprecated in 2019:  [Issue #1684](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1684) / [PR #1878](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/1878)