# How does setuptools installs test dependencies on python setup.py test command

Tags: python, setuptools

When I use the command `python setup.py test`, all of the [documentation](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing.html) I've seen says setuptools will handle installing the testing dependencies. Where does it install them and are they deleted from the machine after the test suite runs? I've noticed none of the testing modules are actually installed into my virtual environment after this command completes.

I understand it takes all of the modules in the `tests_require` list and installs them somewhere but I'm not sure where, what it does with them afterward and why it does this. Also, is there any way to pass arguments to the command without using flags, like with a config file or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It installs them into an automatically-created subdirectory of the code base [named `.eggs`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/dist.py#L750) as `.egg`s. That's because `.egg`s are designed to be importable from any location.

This will thus most likely not work in a modern environment because packages are not distributed as `.egg`s (which lost competition to `.whl`s) so `setuptools` will have to build them from source (with `bdist_egg`). Which is likely to fail for many widely-used binary packages with nontrivial build requirements (not to mention the time needed and the fact that packages are not tested as `.egg`s, either, and may fail when packaged like this).

---

Instead, listing build requirements in `requirements.txt` and invoking `pip install -r requirements.txt` before the build seems to have become widespread practice. This does not make `setup.py` automatically buildable from source by `pip` though.

I tried to install them myself from `setup.py` but this proved to be fragile (e.g. if the user doesn't have write access to `site-packages`).

The best solution adopted by at least a number of high-profile projects seems to be to just make `setup.py` fail if they are not present. This is especially useful if the requirements are not Python but C libraries as `setup.py` doesn't know how to install these in the specific environment anyway. As you can see, this complements `requirements.txt` naturally.

Answer (score 3):

**Avoid `python setup.py test`** and `tests_require`, it's crufty and is now [deprecated](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1684).

That old feature just downloads the test deps to the project's setup directory, which is seldom what the developer wanted or expected to happen! That doesn't work well in a modern CI workflows with virtual environments, where you would want your dependencies installed to site-packages.

[The recommended way to do it using setuptools these days is with an `extras_require` tag.](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1197#issuecomment-290488597). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42179836/674039) for an example.